# Read character by character from a file and put each line in a String

Tags: c, file, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've to read character by character from a file and put each line in a String.
The problem is that i don't know the size of each line so eventually I've to reallocate the memory. So If I try a reallocation my program return error. Am I doing something wrong?

```c
    FILE * file = fopen(input,"r");
    if(file != NULL){
        char temp;
        char * line;
        line =  (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
        int i = 0;
        while((temp = fgetc(file)) != EOF){

            if(temp == '\n'){

                i = 0;
            }
            else{
                if(i > strlen(line) - 2){
                    line = (char *) realloc(line,sizeof(line) * 10);
                }
                line[i] = (char) temp;
                i++;
            }

        }
        free(line);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else{

    }
```

Comment: What is the error? Also, you use `strlen` - is `line` a proper C-string?

Comment: I haven't checked all of this for logic (please give any errors), but sizeof(line) is the size of a pointer, so you're always allocating a fixed 40 or 80 bytes in your loop regardless.

Comment: There is everything wrong with this code. Have you looked into getline?

Comment: the program just crush  and yes @kabanus

Comment: thanks for the tips but changing the sizeof to sizeof(char) for something doesn't solve the problem @teppic

Comment: @david sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1, so you never need that. sizeof(line), assuming it refers to a valid string, is never the length of the string, it's the size of an address. Use strlen(line) for the length.

Comment: `sizeof( line )` is a fixed value.  Probably 4 or 8.  You are always reallocated exactly the same amount of memory.

Comment: I' am a novice of programming in c but i was trying to use fgetc. Can you be more specific about my error? It will help my alot to improve. Is getline better in term of memory usage and performance?  @AnttiHaapala

Comment: @David Take a look at this page https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/the-realloc-function-in-c/ it gives a good overview of how realloc works and example code to study.

Comment: So the only error here is the second parameter of realloc?

Comment: No; there are other errors than just the second parameter of `realloc()`, though that is probably the most critical error. The notation `ptr = realloc(ptr, new_size);` is an incipient memory leak. If the allocation fails, you've just overwritten the pointer to the old data with a null pointer, so you can no longer free what you already have allocated. Use `new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size);` and only assign that to `old_ptr` when you've checked for successful allocation. You apply `strlen()` to an uninitialized string. The `fgetc()` function returns an `int`, not a `char` — and it matters!

Comment: I doubt that the list in my previous comment is complete; I've not scrutinized everything.  But they're issues enough to get you going.

Comment: The posted code is only a snippet.  For us to properly debug your code, you need to post a [mcve], including which header files are being included

Comment: OT: regarding: `line =  (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);`  1) the heap allocation functions return a type `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect, suggest removing that expression.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) 3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "error message" );` to output your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for errors
4. outputs user error messages to `stderr`
5. outputs the text reason the system thinks an error occurred to `stderr`
6. documents why each header file is included
7. shows an example of how to handle the case where the user failed to enter a command line parameter (in this case a input file name)
8. makes use of `size_t` rather than `int` when passing parameters to `malloc()` and `realloc()`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen(), perror(), fclose() fprintf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc(), realloc(). free()


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <fileName>\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    FILE * file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    if( !file )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    int ch;
    char * line =  malloc( 10 );
    if( !line )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        fclose( file );   // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    size_t lineLen = 10;
    size_t i = 0;
    while( (ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF )
    {
        if( ch == '\n' )
        {
            line[i] = '\0';
            // do something with contents of line
            i = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            if(i >= lineLen )
            {
                lineLen *= 2;
                char * temp = realloc( line, lineLen );
                if( !temp )
                {
                    perror( "realloc failed" );
                    // cleanup
                    fclose( file );
                    free( line );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
                line = temp;
            }
            line[i] = (char)ch;
            i++;
        }

    }
    free(line);
    fclose(file);
}
```